# When writing a Perl module, do I have to specifically check for an object instance in all my methods?

Tags: perl, oop

I'm writing a module that has several methods. Let's consider this :

```
package MyPackage;
sub new {
 ...
}

sub do_your_job {
 ...
}
1;
```

What is to stop someone calling `do_your_job` like `MyPackage->do_your_job` instead of `$obj->do_your_job` ? Do I need to check in every method that I'm receiving a reference as the first argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. If your module features only the most minimal documentation, it should be clear from that that `do_your_job` is a method that needs to be called on an object. If someone wants to call that in some other way, it's **his** fault.

Of course, you could check whether the first parameter to your method is a blessed object. But this has at least two drawbacks: You lose a little bit of performance and you clutter your methods with code that really doesn't do anything promised by the method's name.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But, I should check on all the instance methods, and die with a detailed exception anyway, right? For those users that can't be bothered to read the documentation.

Comment: @Geo: no not necessarily right.  At some point you have to trust the user; if you have two methods bar and baz, you aren't magically going to be able to tell that a call to bar was meant to be that, not a call to baz where they forgot the exact method name.

Comment: @Manni: I don't think you meant *mess up* ( http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Amess+up ) but rather something like *"your methods become messy with "*.

Comment: It sounds better after your edit. But isn't a messed up method one that became messy?

Comment: @Sinan: The 'get' was a typo (I'm guessing), but how is "your methods become messy with" any different from "you mess up your methods with"? The link you gave offers "make a mess of" as a definition of 'mess up', so I'm not seeing the any distinction here.

Comment: mess(y) removed and replaced with "clutter". _I_ am happy now.

Comment: @Manni, no "messed up" has a connotation of "broken" that "messy" doesn't.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you. I guess "cluttered" was what I was really aiming for.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to check; you can just document that it's an object method and trust callers to use it as such.  But if you feel that's insufficient, you certainly can check.

Same thing applies to arguments other than the method-call implicit object/class argument.  You might have a parameter that's supposed to be an array ref, or a positive integer less than 10, or an object of some given type, or just about anything else.  One path is to assume callers follow the documentation; the other is to trust nothing.

Answer (score 5):

The short answers in theory are "Nothing" and "That's not a bad idea."

In practice however, the documentation is what solves these problems. There's a common courtesy in the Perl community that instructs developers to only use modules in the manner which they have been documented.

Perl Modules come with no guarantee that the internals will never change. So an implicit agreement is that developers will not dig into the internals of a module/class unless they are implementing that module/class.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, document what your module does and trust the user. However, it is worth thinking about the philosophical difference between a call on a class and a call on an object. If your Perl module provides a way of creating objects, many of the methods in that class are likely to rely on data specific to an individual object. This is probably the most common way of calling methods: once you have an object, you simply do `$object->method(…)`. However, it is likely that some class methods are general and do not need data from a specific object. These are often called using the package name, and this is most commonly seen in calling a `new()` method, such as `LWP::UserAgent->new()`.

Conveniently, Perl allows you to treat these two cases in the same way, using something like `my $self = shift;` at the beginning of the method: if the method is called on an object, `$self` gets the value of the object reference, if called on the class, `$self` gets the package name.

Even if the method is called on a class, so `$self` contains the package name, *you can still call other methods on this package in the same way* by doing `$self->method(…)`. This is then compatible with calling the original method on a specific object, so everything holds together.

As just one example, the Perl [Math::BigInt package](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/Math/BigInt.html) includes quite a lot of methods, some of which are designed to be called on the package (class) itself (e.g. `new()`), some of which are to be called on individual objects (e.g. `round()`), and some on either (e.g. `accuracy()`).

The moral: it should be up to the functionality of the method as to whether it is capable of sensible meaning. It's reasonable to assume that the any method is being called with the expectation that it will do what you advertise it to. However, don't *require* a method call to be on an object when it might make sense for that method to be called on the class itself.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to check the referent of a method call. However, based on what your specific application needs, you may want to:

```
 sub some_method {
      my( $class ) = @_;
      croak( "This is a class method only" ) if ref $class;
      ...
      }
```

Although I tend to not care so much, you might want to check that you have an instance before you try dereferencing something:

```
 sub some_instance_method {
      my( $self ) = @_;
      croak( "This is an instance method only" ) unless ref $self;

      $self->{some_attr};
      }
```

I tend to assume that the higher level will call it as I've documented it, though.