# Perl: When called in a method, can ref($self) ever return anything other than __PACKAGE__ or undef?

Tags: perl, oop

I have method in a class that I need to make sure is only called on an object instance, and not as a class method.

I will probably do something like this:

```
# Edit: this is terrible, don't do this, it breaks inheritance.
sub foo
{
  my ($self) = @_;

  if (ref($self) ne __PACKAGE__) { return; }

  ...do stuff
}
```

But I'm thinking it will be more efficient to do this:

```
sub foo
{
  my ($self) = @_;

  if (not ref($self)) { return; }

  ...do stuff
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it safe to assume that if ref() returns not undef that it will return the current package?
2. I would ideally like to go back through and do something like this in all my methods for sanity checking.  Is that a bad idea?
3. Is there a more perlish way to do what I want?

"Use moose" is not an acceptable answer in this case.  However if you are compelled to say that, please tell me how moose makes this easy or more efficient.  I might want to incorporate it into my own object system.

Thanks!

**EDITED** to reflect that ref never returns undef, only an empty string.

**EDIT 2** Here's a follow up question.  Someone below suggested using:

```
$self->isa(__PACKAGE__)
```

But won't that always succeed?  Unless of course the caller does something really boneheaded like:

```
MyClass::MyMethod($ref_to_some_other_object)
```

Comment: `$self->isa(__PACKAGE__)` will indeed always succeed whether `$self` is an instance of a class that is or derives from `__PACKAGE__` or `$self` contains the name of a package that is or derives from `__PACKAGE__`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html as I pointed out my comment to @kinopiko.

Comment: You might want to look at the comments on this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620393/when-writing-a-perl-module-do-i-have-to-specifically-check-for-an-object-instanc/1620478#1620478

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a duplicate of the question. The question as posed originally looked like my answer to that question.

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634042/can-i-access-a-static-method-in-a-dynamically-specified-class-in-perl

Comment: And to reiterate my comment there: the only really *useful* test is checking whether ref() returns true. Checking for `eq __PACKAGE__` is wrong, and checking for `isa __PACKAGE__` is a fairly weak, almost useless, test so why waste time on it?

Comment: @Sinan: Your isa() code when only suceed when people call the subroutine as a method, so that's slightly less than always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should probably `croak` rather than silently doing nothing because, according to your specs, calling `foo` as a class method is a breach of contract.

Second, just checking if the first argument is a reference is enough. Your method will fail if there is inheritance involved:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package A;
use Carp;

sub new { bless {} => shift }
sub foo {
    croak "I am not in " . __PACKAGE__ unless __PACKAGE__ eq ref(shift)
}

package B;

use base 'A';

package main;

$x = B->new;

$x->foo;
```

```
C:\Temp> t
I am not in A at C:\Temp\t.pl line 19
```

See also [perldoc -f ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html):

> If the referenced object has been blessed into a package, then that package name is returned instead. You can think of `ref` as a `typeof`  operator.

So:

```
sub foo {
    croak "Don't call as class method" unless ref shift;
}
```

Finally, note that `ref` ***never*** returns `undef`.

Is it a good idea to add this check to every method? I guess one could make that argument from a design by contract view.

On the other hand, my methods assume they were called as instance methods and I only check for the possibility of a method being called as a class method if the method can provide a meaningful alternative behavior when called as such.

I cannot remember any modules which have these kinds of checks either.

By the way, instead of

```
sub foo {
    my ($self) = @_;
```

you should use

```
sub foo {
    my $self = shift;
```

leaving only the arguments to the method in `@_` to be unpacked. Or, you should unpack all arguments in one fell swoop:

```
sub foo {
    my ($self, $bar, $baz) = @_;
```

Comment: my($self, $bar,$baz) = @_ is my standard style

Answer (score 4):

> Is it safe to assume that if ref() returns not undef that it will return the current package?

No.

```
my $bar = Bar->new;
Package::Foo::foo($bar);
```

will lead to `foo` putting `$bar` into `$self` and `ref $self` will then return `Bar`.

And, as already noted in the earlier answers, checking for the literal package name rather than testing `isa` breaks inheritance anyhow.

Comment: Indeed. Many things break when people break the social contract of the interface. :(

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the functional form of isa, that way you dont have to check to make sure $self is a reference.  of course, the functional isa has the caveat that packages cant override isa, but i'm torn as to if that's a good or bad thing. in my own code, i usually do something like this, which i find has more useful calling semantics than UNIVERSAL::isa.

```
sub isa {UNIVERSAL::isa @_ > 1 ? shift : $_, @_}

.....

return unless isa $self => __PACKAGE__;

for (@objects) {
    say $_->name if isa 'Package';
}
```